# How Object Masquerading works in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble getting this piece of code as to why the ClassA methods get assigned to ClassB. Specifically, I am not able to understand out the inheritance behaviour of first two lines of code in ClassB.

```
function ClassA(sColor) {
    this.color = sColor;
    this.sayColor = function () {
    alert(this.color);
    }; 
    this.sayColor1 = function () {
    alert("hi");
    };
}

function ClassB(sColor, sName) {
    this.newMethod = ClassA;
    this.newMethod(sColor);
    delete this.newMethod;
    this.name = sName;
    this.sayName = function () {
    alert(this.name);
    };
}

var objA = new ClassA('red');
var objB = new ClassB('blue', 'Nicholas');
objA.sayColor();  
objB.sayColor(); 
objB.sayColor1();
objB.sayName();
```

Comment: You should read about _prototype_ in JS

Comment: and also about _this_ keyword

Comment: For a good introduction to OOP in JavaScript read [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning `ClassA` to be an instance method in `ClassB`, that's not inheritance. If you wish `ClassB` to extend `ClassA`, you can do this in the following way:

```
function ClassB(sColor, sName) {
    ClassA.call(this, sColor);
    // do the rest
}

ClassB.prototype = Object.create(ClassA.prototype);
```

Answer (score 1):

I will try a bit to explain what happens in first two lines in `ClassB`

In the first line, property `newMethod` refers to function `ClassA`

```
    this.newMethod = ClassA;
```

then, in the second line, the function is being called,

```
    this.newMethod(sColor);
```

in this case the function inside `ClassA` refers to object in `ClassB`, so all properties of ClassA are added to created object.

and, at last reference is being deleted

```
    delete this.newMethod;
```

You can do this, simply by writing `ClassA.call(this,sColor);`, instead of these three lines

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with the way you are implementing inheritance in JS

Object masquerading is done in JS this way:

```
function ClassA () { 

} 
function ClassB() { 

    this.superclass = ClassA; 

    this.superclass(); 

    delete this.superclass; 
}
ClassB.prototype = new ClassA;
```

Try implementing it this way...

For more reference you can check :

http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-objects/